# Force close while trying to release WakeLock?

Tags: java, android, screen, wakelock

I have a button that when you click it, it turns on a WakeLock, and that works fine! But when you click it again its suppose to turn WakeLock off, but instead it just crashes the app! Any help would be appreciates, and I know its not because I'm changing images, because that part works fine! :) Heres my code:

```
PowerManager.WakeLock wl; //This is before my oncreate
int stayAwake = 0; //This is before my oncreate

   ((Button) findViewById(R.id.sleepLock)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService (Context.POWER_SERVICE); 
    wl = pm.newWakeLock (PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag"); 
        if (stayAwake == 0) {
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.sleepLock)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.awake);
        stayAwake = 1;
        wl.acquire();
        }else {
            ((Button) findViewById(R.id.sleepLock)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sleep);
            stayAwake = 0;
            wl.release();
        }

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

Logcat:

```
06-06 00:44:25.206: W/dalvikvm(3855): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a031f8)
06-06 00:44:25.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3855): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-06 00:44:25.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3855): java.lang.RuntimeException: WakeLock under-locked My Tag
06-06 00:44:25.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3855):     at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.release(PowerManager.java:325)
06-06 00:44:25.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3855):     at android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.release(PowerManager.java:300)
06-06 00:44:25.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3855):     at com.something.something.SavedGame$5.onClick(SavedGame.java:259)
06-06 00:44:25.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3855):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
06-06 00:44:25.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3855):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
06-06 00:44:25.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3855):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
06-06 00:44:25.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3855):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-06 00:44:25.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3855):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-06 00:44:25.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3855):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-06 00:44:25.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3855):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-06 00:44:25.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3855):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-06 00:44:25.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3855):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
06-06 00:44:25.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3855):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
06-06 00:44:25.230: E/AndroidRuntime(3855):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: 'just crashes' is not a meaningful error report.  Connect ADB, run logcat and post the detailed crash message.

Comment: @Sameer Yeah, the acquire works fine!

Comment: @WilliamL. Did you check my answer?

Comment: Yeah, and it still isn't working, even if I set a separate button to release the sleeplock, I just edited in logcat

Comment: Wake Lock does not have any thing with it.Does not button reference try my code

Comment: I found a solution! I used           getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
and            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
and it works perfect!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you are releasing lock your button does not have any reference as you are again reinitialize button and does not set clickListener

Change your code

```
Button btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.sleepLock);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl; //This is before my oncreate
int stayAwake = 0; //This is before my oncreate

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService (Context.POWER_SERVICE); 
        wl = pm.newWakeLock (PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag"); 
        if (stayAwake == 0) {
            btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.awake);
            stayAwake = 1;
            wl.acquire();
        } else {
            btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sleep);
            stayAwake = 0;
            wl.release();
        }
    }
});
```

Now your code will work fine